# Badge number is not increasing on application icon when user receive more than 1 push notifications

Tags: ios

Badge number is not increasing on application icon when user receive more than 1 push notifications when the application is in background. I am showing the badge number that I am getting from the server. Can we handle this from mobile end in iOS.

Comment: You have to track the number server side, there are plenty of articles/questions (frustrations) out there about this about this.

Answer (score 2):

As per [documented here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) you can send badge number from push notification. What you need to do is track actual badge to be set on webserver and than set it in to dictionary as below.
[image]

So if you send dictionary like below in push notification you will have badge set to 9 automatically you don't need to do anything programatically.

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
    },
}
```

Above can be done through php or .net depending on your server.